# How to use dwolla api on Flutter dart

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want to be able to use the Dwolla api on my flutter project! It would have been easy since most of the work is done in the backend.

Now, there's a part of it that needs the ui, where javascript and html has to be implelmented.

That's where my problem comes...
How do I implement this part of the api in flutter:

> Then, you’ll pass this single-use IAV token to the client-side of your
>   application where it will be used in the JavaScript function
>   dwolla.iav.start. This token will be used to authenticate the request
>   asking Dwolla to render the IAV flow. Before calling this function
>   you’ll want to include dwolla.js in the HEAD of your page.

```
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.dwolla.com/1/dwolla.js"></script>
</head>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.dwolla.com/1/dwolla.js"></script>
</head>
```

> Next, you’ll add in a container to the body of your page where you
>   want to render the IAV flow.

```
<div id="mainContainer">
  <input type="button" id="start" value="Add Bank">
</div>

<div id="iavContainer"></div>
<div id="mainContainer">
  <input type="button" id="start" value="Add Bank">
</div>

<div id="iavContainer"></div>
```

> Now that you have dwolla.js initialized on the page and the container
>   created where you’ll render the IAV flow, you’ll create a JavaScript
>   function that responds to the Customer clicking the “Add bank” button
>   on your page. Once the Customer clicks “Add Bank”, your application
>   will call dwolla.iav.start() passing in the following arguments: a
>   string value of your single-use IAV token, options such as the
>   iavContainer element where IAV will render, and a callback function
>   that will handle any error or response.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#start').click(function() {
  var iavToken = '4adF858jPeQ9RnojMHdqSD2KwsvmhO7Ti7cI5woOiBGCpH5krY';
  dwolla.configure('sandbox');
  dwolla.iav.start(iavToken, {
          container: 'iavContainer',
          stylesheets: [
            'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&subset=latin,latin-ext',
            'http://localhost:8080/iav/customStylesheet.css'
          ],
          microDeposits: 'true',
          fallbackToMicroDeposits: (fallbackToMicroDeposits.value === 'true')
        }, function(err, res) {
    console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err) + ' -- Response: ' + JSON.stringify(res));
  });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#start').click(function() {
  var iavToken = '4adF858jPeQ9RnojMHdqSD2KwsvmhO7Ti7cI5woOiBGCpH5krY';
  dwolla.configure('sandbox');
  dwolla.iav.start(iavToken, {
          container: 'iavContainer',
          stylesheets: [
            'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&subset=latin,latin-ext',
            'http://localhost:8080/iav/customStylesheet.css'
          ],
          microDeposits: 'true',
          fallbackToMicroDeposits: (fallbackToMicroDeposits.value === 'true')
        }, function(err, res) {
    console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err) + ' -- Response: ' + JSON.stringify(res));
  });
});
</script>
```

> "The customer will complete the IAV flow by authenticating with their
>   online banking credentials. You’ll know their bank account was
>   successfully added and verified if you receive a JSON response in your
>   callback that includes a link to the newly created funding source."

Note: Dwolla has no sdk's for mobile.

So I guess my question is, how do you go about integrating such an API on flutter?

Comment: I'm also going to start working on Dwolla with flutter. What would you recommend, should I do it. Did you implement "Javascript and html" part successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Dwolla's IAV should work for mobile apps inside of a [WebView](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter). At the moment there is no way to do it entirely through a backend server via APIs. According to [this post](https://medium.com/flutter/the-power-of-webviews-in-flutter-a56234b57df2), it looks like the Flutter team has created a plugin that allows you to incorporate WebViews into your Flutter app. Unfortunately you will need to host a webpage that includes the Dwolla.js Javascript library in order to facilitate this flow. We're continuing to look for ways to enhance this solution and provide additional resources for developers looking to do everything within their native mobile applications.

Comment: Any good news for mobile application developers specifically flutter?